# What does location mean in my Rails logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, location

Here's an example output:

> 13:25:29 log.1    | method=GET path=/users/auth/github/callback
>   format=html controller=users/omniauth_callbacks action=github
>   status=302 duration=829.94 view=0.00 db=25.57
>   location=http://loclhost:5000/heroku/in-stcks/
>   params={"code"=>"xxxxxxxx",
>   "state"=>"xxxxxxxx"}

What is the `location` field in this line, and where is it loaded from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using the [lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) gem for logging. There, the `location` field is set if the request was answered with an HTTP redirect (i.e. an `HTTP 301` or `HTTP 302`). The field contains the full URL where the user was forwarded to.

The field is called `location` because that's the name of the HTTP header containing this field in the response.